# ptr_map and pointer

Tags: boost, reference, dictionary, pointers, abstract

I'm using ptr_map from boost for storing objects derived from some base abstract type.

```
class Entity { virtual void foo() = 0; };
class Entity1 : public Entity {};
class Entity2 : public Entity {};

boost::ptr_map<string, Entity> someMap; // We could store pointers for abstract type
```

Inserting works great:

```
someMap.insert("someKey", new Entity1());
someMap.insert("someKey", new Entity2());
```

But not returning from map:

```
template<typename EntityType>
EntityType *GetEntity(const string &entityName)
{
    return dynamic_cast<EntityType*>(&someMap[entityName]);
}

GetEntity<Entity1>(entityName);
```

Now the problem: **operator[]** of ptr_map returns reference! So in constructur there could be calling type from value.
Now compiler fails with error:

```
 instantiated from ‘EntityType* EntityManager::GetEntity(const std::string&) [with EntityType = Entity1, std::string = std::basic_string<char>]’
error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘Entity’
```

If there is any method in ptr_map which returns pointer to the value, there woudln't be any problems. What could  you say about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An oft forgotten fact is that operator[] will instantiate the key if it doesn't exist. This is a problem in your case because the key is abstract.
So instead, use at().
That is,

```
return dynamic_cast<EntityType*>(&someMap.at(entityName));
```

For more info, read the ["Semantics: lookup"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_map_adapter.html) section

BTW, I would question your design decision to expose raw pointers stored within container whose very purpose is to alleviate memory management.

Comment: probably you mean: operator[] will instantiate the value/object, not the key. Also, the key is not abstract here.