# casting pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, reference, boost-any

I'm using ptr_map for storing different types of pointers.

```
boost::ptr_map<string, any> someMap;
```

I store there some templated class objects:

```
someMap.insert("1", new SomeClass<int>());
someMap.insert("2", new SomeClass<float>());
```

Now I want to get values from map. Here is a sample with references:

```
template<typename T>
T &get(const string &someKey)
{
    try
    {
        return any_cast<EventType&>(mSignalAssociation.at(signalName));
    } catch(bad_any_cast &e)
    {
        // Logging here
    }
}

get< SomeClass<int> >("1"); // This works
```

But I don't like references, because I can't return, for example, NULL if the casting is bad or the object doesn't exist.

How can I get pointer from this map?

```
T *get(const string &someKey)
{
   return any_cast<EventType*>(mSignalAssociation.at(signalName));
}
```

This builds but fails at casting, why?

Comment: Why are you using a `ptr_map`? `any` has value semantics, so it can be stored in a plain `map`.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking about. The `ptr_map` store a pointer to its argument so we have a pointer to a small structure which itself as a pointer to the real object. Talk about premature pessimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this:

```
T *get(const string &someKey)
{
   return &any_cast<EventType&>(mSignalAssociation.at(signalName));
}
```

(Just a guess)

Comment: Taking the address (& operator) of a reference variable gives you the address of the object the reference variable references.

Answer (score 1):

> Function any_cast
>
> If passed a pointer,
> it returns a similarly qualified
> pointer to the value content if
> successful, otherwise null is
> returned. If T is ValueType, it
> returns a copy of the held value,
> otherwise, if T is a reference to
> (possibly const qualified) ValueType,
> it returns a reference to the held
> value.

What you want are the pointer semantics. Also stop using ptr_map, it's a waste as has been pointed out in the comments.

```
map<string, any> someMap;
someMap["1"] = SomeClass<int>();
someMap["2"] = SomeClass<float>();

// this will be a valid pointer because someMap["1"] stores 
// an object of SomeClass<int>
SomeClass<int>* valid_ptr = any_cast<SomeClass<int> >(&someMap["1"]);

// this will be null pointer because someMap["2"] doesn't store
// an object of SomeClass<int>
SomeClass<int>* invalid_ptr = any_cast<SomeClass<int> >(&someMap["2"]);
```

If you need to store pointers for some reason to these SomeClass objects, then I think you'll have to do the memory management yourself (manually free the elements stored in any) and use an extra level of indirection to detect cast failures with a null pointer. Probably better to use something like boost::shared_ptr if you do.

```
map<string, any> someMap;
someMap["1"] = new SomeClass<int>();
someMap["2"] = new SomeClass<float>();

// this will be a valid pointer because someMap["1"] stores 
// an object of SomeClass<int>*
SomeClass<int>** valid_ptr = any_cast<SomeClass<int>*>(&someMap["1"]);

// this will be a null pointer because someMap["1"] does
// not store an object of SomeClass<int>*
SomeClass<int>** invalid_ptr = any_cast<SomeClass<int>*>(&someMap["2"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't like references, because I
>   can't return, for example, NULL if the
>   casting is bad or the object doesn't
>   exist

Ah... so that is the reason why you are doing these gymnastics with pointers, references, casting and memory managing containers! :)

As I pointed out [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128296/ptr-map-and-pointer); this will create unnecessary headaches.
Fortunately, your problem has been solved - just look at [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).